# How can i recive data from jQuery .load('path',{ par1 : val, 'par2' : val }) in action

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

My solution to recive data in action that have no result:

jQuery Function:

```
$('#searchbtn').click(function () {
    var firstname = $("#txtFirstName").val();
    var lastname = $("#txtLName").val();
    $('#AjaxGridContent').load('@Url.Content("~/Home/SearchInfo")', { txtFirstName: firstname, txtLastName: lastname });
    return;
});
```

Action code:

```
[HttpGet]    
public PartialViewResult SearchInfo(string txtFirstName = "", string txtLastName = "")
        {
            var model = BlUser.Select().Where(p => p.FirstName.Contains(txtFirstName) && p.LastName.Contains(txtLastName)).ToList();
            return PartialView("_PartialUserWebGrid", model);
        }
```

Action have no recive data.

What is correct way?

Comment: Were you able to hit any breakpoint on your Controller's method?

Comment: Check your browser console It will path issue. You should use `@Url.Action("SearchInfo","Home")`